# Create a access token(JWT) which is valid only for a phone

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I work on a project that uses tokens (jwt) to authenticate users in the mobile app. I wanted to know that there is a way that every token is valid only for a phone? For example, the token received by the user in the application does not work in software such as Postman or another phone

Comment: This is simply not possible. Any request the mobile device makes can also be made by any other client, like for example Postman.

Comment: @GaborLengyel The problem exactly is this, any request can be maked or simulated. Do you have a solution? Or do you can introduce a paper or source?

Comment: Your best bet is to integrate auth workflow with hardware backed cryptographic features such as Apple's Secure Enclave. This requires to create a key-pair on each new device and, you then would need to register the public key with your server and use it to create some kind of secret as part of the JWT, which the phone must then decrypt and send it in addition to the JWT as part of a confirmation. If you limit usage of each secret to one request and use ssl + short JWT validity this can be pretty secure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## THE PROBLEM

> I wanted to know that there is a way that every token is valid only for a phone? For example, the token received by the user in the application does not work in software such as Postman or another phone

Well you found yourself a very hard but not impossible problem to solve. Yes, in the context of a mobile API its possible to solve it, and the concept is known as *Mobile App Attestation*.

So let's dive in your problem in phases...

> I work on a project that uses tokens (jwt) to authenticate users in the mobile app.

To authenticate a request in an API server you need to know 2 things, **WHO** is doing the request and **WHAT** is doing the request, otherwise you will never be able to assert that the user is really a human, and not something else.

Let me clarify this common misconception about **WHO** vs **WHAT** is accessing your API server.

## The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

To better understand the differences between the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are accessing an API server, let’s use this picture:

[image: Man in the Middle Attack]

The Intended Communication Channel represents the mobile app being used as you expected, by a legit user without any malicious intentions, using an untampered version of the mobile app, and communicating directly with the API server without being man in the middle attacked.

The actual channel may represent several different scenarios, like a legit user with malicious intentions that may be using a repackaged version of the mobile app, a hacker using the genuine version of the mobile app, while man in the middle attacking it, to understand how the communication between the mobile app and the API server is being done in order to be able to automate attacks against your API. Many other scenarios are possible, but we will not enumerate each one here.

I hope that by now you may already have a clue why the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are not the same, but if not it will become clear in a moment.

The **WHO** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

> [OAUTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)
>
> Generally, OAuth provides to clients a "secure delegated access" to server resources on behalf of a resource owner. It specifies a process for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials. Designed specifically to work with Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), OAuth essentially allows access tokens to be issued to third-party clients by an authorization server, with the approval of the resource owner. The third party then uses the access token to access the protected resources hosted by the resource server.
>
> [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/)
>
> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.

While user authentication may let the API server know **WHO** is using the API, it cannot guarantee that the requests have originated from **WHAT** you expect, the original version of the mobile app.

Now we need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling the API server, and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of the mobile app, or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around with the API server, using a tool like Postman?

For your surprise you may end up discovering that It can be one of the legit users using a repackaged version of the mobile app or an automated script that is trying to gamify and take advantage of the service provided by the application.

Well, to identify the **WHAT**, developers tend to resort to an API key that usually they hard-code in the code of their mobile app. Some developers go the extra mile and compute the key at run-time in the mobile app, thus it becomes a runtime secret as opposed to the former approach when a static secret is embedded in the code.

The above write-up was extracted from an article I wrote, entitled *WHY DOES YOUR MOBILE APP NEED AN API KEY?*, and that you can read in full [here](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key), that is the first article in a series of articles about API keys.

## DEFENDING AN API SERVER

Depending on your budget and resources you may employ an array of different approaches and techniques to defend your API server, and I will start to enumerate some of the most usual ones, but before I do it so I would like to leave this note:

> As a best practice a mobile app or a web app should only communicate with an API server that is under your control and any access to third party APIs services must be done by this same API server you control. This way you limit the attack surface to only one place, where you will employ as many layers of defense as what you are protecting is worth.

You can start with [reCaptcha V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html), followed by [Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall)(WAF) and finally if you can afford it a [User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics)(UBA) solution.

Google [reCAPTCHA V3](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html):

> reCAPTCHA is a free service that protects your website from spam and abuse. reCAPTCHA uses an advanced risk analysis engine and adaptive challenges to keep automated software from engaging in abusive activities on your site. It does this while letting your valid users pass through with ease.
>
> ...helps you detect abusive traffic on your website without any user friction. It returns a score based on the interactions with your website and provides you more flexibility to take appropriate actions.

[WAF - Web Application Firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall):

> A web application firewall (or WAF) filters, monitors, and blocks HTTP traffic to and from a web application. A WAF is differentiated from a regular firewall in that a WAF is able to filter the content of specific web applications while regular firewalls serve as a safety gate between servers. By inspecting HTTP traffic, it can prevent attacks stemming from web application security flaws, such as SQL injection, cross-site scripting (XSS), file inclusion, and security misconfigurations.

[UBA - User Behavior Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_behavior_analytics):

> User behavior analytics (UBA) as defined by Gartner is a cybersecurity process about detection of insider threats, targeted attacks, and financial fraud. UBA solutions look at patterns of human behavior, and then apply algorithms and statistical analysis to detect meaningful anomalies from those patterns—anomalies that indicate potential threats. Instead of tracking devices or security events, UBA tracks a system's users. Big data platforms like Apache Hadoop are increasing UBA functionality by allowing them to analyze petabytes worth of data to detect insider threats and advanced persistent threats.

All this solutions work based on a negative identification model, by other words they try their best to differentiate the bad from the good by identifying what is bad, not what is good, thus they are prone to false positives, despite of the advanced technology used by some of them, like machine learning and artificial intelligence.

So you may find yourself more often than not in having to relax how you block the access to the API server in order to not affect the good users. This also means that this solutions require constant monitoring to validate that the false positives are not blocking your legit users and that at same time they are properly keeping at bay the unauthorized ones.

Regarding APIs serving mobile apps a positive identification model can be used by using a Mobile App Attestation solution that guarantees to the API server that the requests can be trusted without the possibility of false positives.

## A POSSIBLE BETTER SOLUTION

> I wanted to know that there is a way that every token is valid only for a phone? For example, the token received by the user in the application does not work in software such as Postman or another phone

I already reveled that it can be solved by implementing the *Mobile App Attestation** concept, thus lets see how it works...

### Mobile App Attestation

The role of a Mobile App Attestation solution is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered with, is not running in a rooted device, not being instrumented by a framework like xPosed or Frida, not being MitM attacked, and this is achieved by running an SDK in the background. The service running in the cloud will challenge the app, and based on the responses it will attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on, thus the SDK will never be responsible for any decisions.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

[xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too much). It's also easy to undo.

[MiTM Proxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/)

> An interactive TLS-capable intercepting HTTP proxy for penetration testers and software developers.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

Now the App must sent with every API call the JWT token in the headers of the request. This will allow the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

The Mobile App Attestation service already exists as a SAAS solution at Approov(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS, Android, React Native and others. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token issued by the cloud service. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.

## SUMMARY

So you learned that your problem can be solved, but in the end, the solution to use in order to protect your API server must be chosen in accordance with the value of what you are trying to protect and the legal requirements for that type of data, like the GDPR regulations in Europe.

## DO YOU WANT TO GO THE EXTRA MILE?

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you need is an unique fingerprint of the device. I suggest using this library [Valve/fingerprintjs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2).

Once you generated the device unique fingerprint, you can send this fingerprint to authentication server at token generation phase so that it can be used as a salt to generate the JWT signature.

Finally, when the device send back the JWT to server to authenticate, it MUST also send its own fingerprint. The server will then use this fingerprint to check the JWT signature.

Because the fingerprint generated by that library is unique for each device, it also makes sure that the JWT is only applied for that only device.

EDIT:
@GaborLengyel I didn't want to go that far since I assumed the question was to prevent normal users from using token on multiple devices. But since you asked, I suggest creating a hash generator with the secret provided uniquely for each device at the time the application is installed. The hash string MUST be generated and verified based on:

1. the unique secret mentioned above. Note that this secret is also used as the salt to generate JWT signature
2. the timestamp calculated from when the request is sent (the rule to define these timestamps is predefined between hash generator on client and hash checker on server so that both can parallel come up with the same timestamp without communicate with each other)

So, to secure the web service, every request has to be routed through this hash generator where it will attach the hash string to request header in order to be recognised by the web server. The web server then calculated the timestamp, scan through its secret database to find the one that matched the hash sent from client. Then use that secret to verify the JWT.

Such algorithm to come up with the same timestamp at the time sending the request on client and receiving it on server is quite easy to establish. For example: given the timeout for a request is 3 sec, it could be the next timestamp (T) such that: `T % 3 == 0` on client side and on web server the matching timestamp is either the next or previous timestamp divisible by 3.

Each token only has a short time-to-live (3s in the case above) due to the timestamp generated in this way so it can not be used somewhere else. The only way I can think of to hack this is to reverse-engineer the hash generator and find the secret within.

Comment: Thanks for the help. is this used for mobile applications?

Comment: @FarhadZamani it's a javascript library so if your mobile application is written in javascript then yes. If not you can search for the similar library in your langugue of choice.

Comment: And what keeps an attacker from requesting a jwt from the server (that acts as a token oracle) with any arbitrary fingerprint, and then use that from any device? Or to get the fingerprint of that particular device, and use its token along with its fingerprint to authenticate from anywhere else? The threat this solution mitigates is very specific. Basically it only protects against unintentional error and very naive copying.

Answer (score 0):

Any request can be simulated.
This is almost impossible
You can use refresh token
Decrease your token time
They will expire quickly if someone reaches the accessed